# Why does $x+y=n$ on a square lattice never have the last interior points digit $2, 4, 7$ or $9$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry

Graph the line $x+y=n$ on a square lattice.

Define the number of interior points as

$\large I = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$

For example, if $n = 7$ then $I = 15$

[image: n=7]

Ran a program to compute $I$ for each $n$.
Notice the last $I$ digit is never $2, 4, 7$ or $9$. Why?

```
n = 3   I = 1   
n = 7   I = 15  
n = 9   I = 28
n = 11  I = 45  
n = 13  I = 66  
n = 17  I = 120 
n = 19  I = 153 
n = 21  I = 190
n = 23  I = 231 
n = 27  I = 325
n = 29  I = 378 
n = 31  I = 435
n = 33  I = 496
n = 37  I = 630
```

Comment: See e.g. https://mathcentral.quora.com/Show-that-no-triangular-number-has-its-last-digit-2-4-7-or-9

Comment: Division by $2$ causes a digit $9$ to require a final digit $8$ prior to division, which only occurs for $1\cdot 8, 2\cdot 4, 3\cdot 6, 6\cdot 8$, none of which are consecutive digits.  Repeat this analysis for the other digits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically boils down to showing that the expression $t_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ can never have $2,4,7$ or $9$ in its units place.

Notice that $8t+1=(2n+1)^2$, but
$$8⋅2+1≡7(\text{mod}10) \\8⋅4+1≡3(\text{mod}10) \\8⋅7+1≡7(\text{mod}10) \\8⋅9+1≡3(\text{mod}10)$$
and, we know that a square number cannot end with $3$ or $7$.

Comment: Nice! So to calculate the number of interior points for $n$ is equivalent to $t_k$ where $k=n-2$. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes, of course!